# Убрать панель действий из раздела "Главное" 1С

Tags: 1с

Подскажите, как убрать панель действий из раздела "Главное" 1с?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используется самописная конфигурация.

Comment: Сам раздел "Главное"?!

Comment: Мышкой через настройки панели или отними права на разделы

Comment: @Sagittarius нет, просто убрать жёлтую полосу под главное (стрелкой выделил).

Comment: @eri это как мышкой через настройки, можно более подробный гайд

Comment: @ЕгорКоротцев, у меня нет такой полоски. Создал конфигурацию пустую и проверил.

Comment: @ЕгорКоротцев, а! понял в чём причина!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно настроить панели.

1. Настройки - Настройка Панелей
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Перетащить "Панель функций текущего раздела" в неиспользуемые
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]